# How to properly group parametrized tests in Pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm currently using the following combination of Pytest hooks to customize node ids for a particular module:

```py
# In test_module.py
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if not is_relevant_metafunc(metafunc):
        return
    args = []
    fids = []
    for test_class, test_name, test_args in collect_external_tests():
        args.append(test_args)
        fids.append("Tests.%s.%s" % (test_class, test_name))

    metafunc.parametrize(["arg1", "arg2"], args, ids=fids)

# In conftest.py
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    for item in items:
        if not is_relevant_item(item):
            continue
        item._nodeid = item.callspec.id
        item._location = tuple(list(item.location)[:-1] + [item.callspec.id])
```

The mean reason for this is that I'd like the parametrized tests to be split in different sections ("classes") in the output JUnit XML file, which can then be aggregated and displayed separately.

By default, pytest creates the following hierarchy:

```
root
 |_ test_module
    |_ test_module.test_func[param_a_1]
    |_ test_module.test_func[param_b_2]
    |_ ...
    |_ test_module.test_func[param_z_36]
```

I'd like to have something similar to the following hierarchy:

```
root
 |_ test_module
    |_ a
       |_ test_module.test_func[param_a_1]
       |_ ...
       |_ test_module.test_func[param_a_25]
    |_ b
       |_ test_module.test_func[param_b_1]
       |_ ...
       |_ test_module.test_func[param_b_12]
    |_ ...
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: JUnit spec doesn't have a concept of sections, but it allowes nested suites - maybe you can use these instead. However, `pytest` doesn't group tests in suites (there is only one root testsuite that contains all tests), so you will need to do some report post-processing in hooks.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the terminology (the name of the XML attribute is "classname"). But you're right, Pytest doesn't really support grouping in XML reports, which is really annoying when you generate a lot of tests...

Comment: `classname` is just an attribute of the `testcase` node, it won't introduce a new parent node to group the tests. Here's an idea - maybe you don't need to group at all? Introduce custom properties and filter by them where you consume the report ( if you have control over the consumer).